# Android SQLite CustomAdapter and Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I am a very new android developer and I have been trying to learn it by creating simple apps.

Right now I'm stuck on trying to create a custom ListView for my app.

My data's are being stored in SQLite and I'm calling these data's as a List. I can't seem to find a website to demonstrate how to get SQLite data's to work with Custom ListView.

Below are my data's and I hope someone can help me with setting up my custom adapter to work with my sqlite data's.

**Records.java**

```
public class Records {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private float mf;
    private float mftop;
    private float mfbot;
    private float mfleft;
    private float mfright;
    private float rf;
    private float rftop;
    private float rfbot;
    private float rfleft;
    private float rfright;
    private float tb;
    private float tbtop;
    private float tbbot;
    private float tbleft;
    private float tbright;
    private float bridge;
    private float bridgel;
    private float bridger;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Middle Finger
    public float getMF() {
        return mf;
    }

    public void setMF(float mf) {
        this.mf = mf;
    }

    public float getMFTop() {
        return mftop;
    }

    public void setMFTop(float mftop) {
        this.mftop = mftop;
    }

    public float getMFBot() {
        return mfbot;
    }

    public void setMFBot(float mfbot) {
        this.mfbot = mfbot;
    }

    public float getMFLeft() {
        return mfleft;
    }

    public void setMFLeft(float mfleft) {
        this.mfleft = mfleft;
    }

    public float getMFRight() {
        return mfright;
    }

    public void setMFRight(float mfright) {
        this.mfright = mfright;
    }

    //Ring Finger
    public float getRF() {
        return rf;
    }

    public void setRF(float rf) {
        this.rf = rf;
    }

    public float getRFTop() {
        return rftop;
    }

    public void setRFTop(float rftop) {
        this.rftop = rftop;
    }

    public float getRFBot() {
        return rfbot;
    }

    public void setRFBot(float rfbot) {
        this.rfbot = rfbot;
    }

    public float getRFLeft() {
        return rfleft;
    }

    public void setRFLeft(float rfleft) {
        this.rfleft = rfleft;
    }

    public float getRFRight() {
        return rfright;
    }

    public void setRFRight(float rfright) {
        this.rfright = rfright;
    }

    //Thumb
    public float getTB() {
        return tb;
    }

    public void setTB(float tb) {
        this.tb = tb;
    }

    public float getTBTop() {
        return tbtop;
    }

    public void setTBTop(float tbtop) {
        this.tbtop = tbtop;
    }
    public float getTBBot() {
        return tbbot;
    }

    public void setTBBot(float tbbot) {
        this.tbbot = tbbot;
    }
    public float getTBLeft() {
        return tbleft;
    }

    public void setTBLeft(float tbleft) {
        this.tbleft = tbleft;
    }
    public float getTBRight() {
        return tbright;
    }

    public void setTBRight(float tbright) {
        this.tbright = tbright;
    }

    //Bridge
    public float getBridge() {
        return bridge;
    }

    public void setBridge(float bridge) {
        this.bridge = bridge;
    }

    public float getBridgeL() {
        return bridgel;
    }

    public void setBridgeL(float bridgel) {
        this.bridgel = bridgel;
    }

    public float getBridgeR() {
        return bridger;
    }

    public void setBridgeR(float bridger) {
        this.bridger = bridger;
    }

    //Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NTAdapter> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    NTAdapter data[] = null;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, NTAdapter[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        DataHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new DataHolder();
            holder.dataName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dataName);
            holder.dataType = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dataType);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (DataHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        NTAdapter ntadapter = data[position];
        holder.dataName.setText(ntadapter.name);
        holder.dataType.setText(ntadapter.type);

        return row;
    }

    static class DataHolder {
        TextView dataName;
        TextView dataType;
    }

}
```

**NTAdapter.java**

```
public class NTAdapter {

    public int id;
    public String name, type;

    public NTAdapter() {
        super();
    }

    public NTAdapter(int id, String name, String type) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

**DataLayout.java**

```
public class DataLayout extends ListActivity {
    private RecordsDataSource datasource;

    Button btnDataCancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_layout);


        datasource = new RecordsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Records> values = datasource.getAllRecords();

        //use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
        //elements in a ListView
        ArrayAdapter<Records> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Records>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        /**
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.data_layout_listview, values);
        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        */

        Button btnDataCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDataCancel);

        //Cancel Button
        btnDataCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent goMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(goMain);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }


}
```

Please note that within my DataLayout.java, I have been trying to get my sqlite data's to work with my custom listview setup.

```
        /**
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.data_layout_listview, values);
        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        */
```

I do know that my problem is that my NTAdapter.java and my CustomAdapter.java aren't being setup properly. However, I don't know how to fix it so that it will accept the list of data's which are being stored in ***values***

As the code started to get abit too long to read, I didn't post my other classes. But please do note that everything is working fine if I'm not using my custom listview, as it is not yet working.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

edit: Also, I know that NTAdapter isn't really needed, but I don't know how to make it so that my CustomAdapter.java will get the data's from my **values** and uses them to setup my custom ListView.

edit2: For those that are wondering what **values** is, please refer to **DataLayout.java**.

.

Comment: Please do note that if anyone request any other information, please do let me know. Thank you again for helping.

Comment: What are you using ntadapter for ?

Comment: @Tapan Thaker
NTAdapter was from a tutorial on a website, which stores data's as a string.  
From this website: http://goo.gl/aedwI
I thought I needed something back then, but I realized that it is just like my "values" which stores all my data's. 
I know that if I can find a way to get the data's from my "values" I won't need the NTAdapter.
If you need anymore information please do let me know. I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing while making a CustomAdapter is that you are trying to pass a List
to a constructor which accepts NTAdapter array . So your program is not supposed to work properly.

What you could do is make your CustomAdapter class something like the following :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Records> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
List<Records> data;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Records> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data=data;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View row = convertView;
    DataHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new DataHolder();
        holder.dataName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dataName);
        holder.dataType = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dataType);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (DataHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Records records = data.get(position);
    holder.dataName.setText(records.getName());
    holder.dataType.setText(records.getType());

    return row;
}

static class DataHolder {
    TextView dataName;
    TextView dataType;
}
```

Comment: I would really like to thank you for helping me solve the problem.
After using your solution and adding some tweaks to my code, it is working like a charm. Thank you so much.
I wished I could upvote for you, however, my rep isn't greater than 15 yet, so sorry.
Once again, thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: Its fine , just sharing knowledge :)